# Fridge popping breaker when plugged into garage outlets

Tags: electrical

I moved a fridge into my garage.  After about 2 mos, it started popping the breaker.  I tried the other outlet in the garage, same thing.  I ran a heavy-duty extension cord to a storage room off the garage and it is working fine.  Just as an FYI, the home was built in 1986 and the fridge is a side-by-side about 10-yr-old.  There were no problems with the breaker when the fridge was in the kitchen. Also, I can run my electric weed eater and leaf blower off the outlets in the garage with no problem.

Comment: I'd guess something's up with the fridge.  First place to check (ewww) is the fan next to the cooling coils - either under or behind the fridge -- to see if there's junk or a dead rodent jamming the fan. Since the fridge ran ok for a couple months, something is causing a startup load to exceed design parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a GFCI breaker, then it's common for fridges and GFCIs to not get along so well.

If it's not a GFCI receptacle, you'll want to make sure the fridge is not overloading the circuit. If you've added anything new to the circuit, then that may be the case.

If neither of these are true, then it could be as simple as the breaker going bad. They are a mechanical device, and can go bad.

Comment: Was the original breaker 20A and the one you put the extension cord into and the current one a 15A ? Other than this I agree with Tester